# get number of the binary % operator iterations

Tags: c++

I am trying to find out how many times % has substracted a number from another.

For an example if 256 % 50 = 6, then the iterations have been 5? 256 - 50 - 50 - 50 - 50 - 50.

If 145 % 40 = 25, then the iterations have been 3. 145 - 40 - 40 - 40.

I am looking for a solution to the problem without usiong any kind of loop, recursion or goto.

Comment: 256 % 50 = 6 not 16

Comment: 256 / 50 = 5; 145 / 40 = 3.

Comment: The `%` operator doesn't do any iterations or subtractions. It computes the remainder, in a single CPU instruction. What you're looking for is the `/` operator, although your question is very unclearly expressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `/` operator.

Try the division operator instead of the modulus operator. Works every time. It's fundamental math.

Comment: For positive numbers at least. Otherwise depends on how `%` is defined, which changed between standards iirc.